# Entry Point for CFI implementation in clang/llvm?

Tags: security, compiler-construction, llvm-clang, control-flow, memory-safety

I want to implement Control-Flow Integrity in Clang/llvm. (I know there is Forward-Edge CFI already implemented)

My problem is, that I have never implemented anything for a compiler (I am new to compiler based approaches) and therefore don't know where to start.
For my implementation I need first to get a list of all calls (internal => no library calls) and than change how functions are ended (for example: `pop + jmp` instead of `ret`).

Does anyone know where to start or even if this is possible using the plugin system (LibClang, Clang Plugins, LibTooling)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here is a advanced one CCFI :
https://bitbucket.org/CCFI/

it based on this : 
http://iot.stanford.edu/pubs/mashtizadeh-ccfi-ccs15.pdf

you can learn that how to add your code to each jmp,call,jmp,ret and so on...